# PrimeNG (5.2.4) Tree - Can't expand tree nodes by clicking

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

**Background**: I'm trying to use PrimeNG's Tree component, but I'm encountering the following error when I click to expand a node:

```
UITreeNode.html:6 ERROR TypeError: eventTarget.className.indexOf is not a function
    at Tree.onNodeClick (tree.js:270)
    at UITreeNode.onNodeClick (tree.js:48)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UITreeNode.html:6)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at eval (core.js:10629)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
```

Tracing the error, it looks like the code in question is here:

```
Tree.prototype.onNodeClick = function (event, node) {
        var eventTarget = event.target;
        if (eventTarget.className && eventTarget.className.indexOf('ui-tree-toggler') === 0) {
            return;
        }
```

**Further digging**: I added a click event to my tree in order to see what the event looked like (albeit this might be totally wrong since this might be separate from what the actual error is) and found that when you click on a node, this is what returns:

```
SVGAnimatedString {
    baseVal: "svg-inline--fa fa-caret-right fa-w-6 ui-tree-toggler fa-fw", 
    animVal: "svg-inline--fa fa-caret-right fa-w-6 ui-tree-toggler fa-fw"
}
```

**Other possibly relevant dependencies and code**:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
"primeng": "^5.2.4"
```

**Tree code**:

```
<p-tree [value]="files" (click)="log($event)"></p-tree>
```

Files is just the default file that was provided in the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree).

**Log method:**

```
log(event) {
  console.log(event.target.className);
}
```

**Question**: I can't seem to replicate it in stackblitz or plnkr, so perhaps there's some renegade code that affects the trees?

Or maybe my version of PrimeNG/Angular is out of date and this was fixed in an upgrade?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you please provide code of your log() method?

Comment: @Woworks Edited post to include log() at the bottom. It's just a simple console.log of the event.

Comment: did you try (onNodeExpand)="loadNode($event)" like in documentation?

Comment: I did -- unfortunately the above `onNodeClick` event fires first and errors out before I even get the chance to capture the event from `onNodeExpand` :(

Comment: btw, found the same issue like yours - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984226/error-on-click-event-of-tree-component-of-primeng

Comment: Yup, saw this too. Unfortunately the stackblitz link doesn't replicate the error and doesn't really give me much information on what could be going wrong. The only thing that I can think of is that I might need to upgrade to 6.0.0, but I've also been proven wrong by older stackblitz's that have older versions of PrimeNG running Trees correctly. I wonder if other code can interfere with the inner workings of PrimeNG?

Comment: did you find this one https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=55611 ?

Comment: Yup, this one too. I'd prefer not to downgrade but if need be then I guess that'll have to happen!